# Run springboot application every 1 minut and with synchronise every controller

Tags: java, spring, oracle, spring-boot

I developed spring-boot application with 4 controllers and I need to run the first one after is finished the seconde controller launched to do some work and the there and finally the fourth one, I do @Scheduled(fixedRate = 30000)  for every controller, but with this solution, I don't have a synchro between the 4 controllers, I need to help me with a solution to run it with synchro or another solution to automatically run all controller together with priority. and i attached the code architecture

```
@CrossOrigin("*")
@RestController

public class collector{
@Autowired
    DataSource datasource;
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 40000)
    public  void collector( )  
    {
// the methodes 
}
}
```

```
@CrossOrigin("*")
@RestController

public class Loader {
@Autowired
    DataSource datasource;
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 40000)
    public  void loador( )  
    {
// the methodes 
}
}
```

```
@CrossOrigin("*")
@RestController

public class export{
@Autowired
    DataSource datasource;
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 40000)
    public  void export( )  
    {
// the methodes 
}
}
```

```
@CrossOrigin("*")
@RestController

public class send{
@Autowired
    DataSource datasource;
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 40000)
    public  void send( )  
    {
// the methodes 
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not how schedulers in Spring work. Since you want to execute each method synchronously right after the previous one has finished, schedule just the one that triggers the chain of methods and feel free to call them inside the scheduled method.

```
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 40000)
public  void collector() {
    // the methods             // body of the 1st one
    this.loader.loador();      // 2nd one
    this.export.export();      // 3rd one
    this.send.send();          // 4th one
}
```

Comment: Thnak you , but i'm using jdbcTemplate inside each controller then i can't write it public static to call it from another controller

Comment: You cannot to have them static. What I suggest is to keep the controllers implementation-free and only call the service layer. In the service layer, there is the method annotated as `@Async`. Autowire these services in the class the `@Scheduled` is used and call them as you are used from the controller, yet the difference the entry point here is the scheduled method. Actually, scheduled methods have nothing common with controllers.